# Laravel | Нужна помощь с отправкой письма на почту

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, sendmail

Посмотрел множество видеоуроков и статей, но так и не нашел того, что нужно мне
Все либо используют mailtrap, либо посылают письмо на почту, но оно не приходит, т.к у пользователя должен быть включен параметр "Ненадежные приложения, у которых есть доступ к аккаунту", который само собой ни у кого не включен.

Еще хотелось бы спросить - Зачем он нужен mailtrap? Если при разработке письма отправляются на mailtrap, будут ли они отправляться на тот же mailtrap, а не пользователю в рабочем проекте. Прошу объясните.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: mailtrap для множества тестов предназначен, не для "рабочих" проектов. В чём проблема? В доках достаточно подробно описано использование стандартного [https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#introduction](Swift Mailer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отправки письма лучше использовать очередь. Код из учебного проекта

-- Контроллер:

```
class ContactPageController extends Controller
{
    ...
        public function send(ContactFormRequest $request){
            
            $emailJob = (new SendContactFormJob($request->first_name, $request->last_name, $request->email, $request->subject, $request->message))->delay(now()->addSeconds(3));
            dispatch($emailJob);
        }
    }
```

-- Задача:

```
class SendContactFormJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $email;
    private $subject;
    private $message;
    
    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $email, $subject, $message)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
       Mail::to(env('MAIL_USERNAME'))->send(new ContactForm($this->firstName, $this->lastName, $this->email, $this->subject, $this->message));
    }
```

--Класс, отвечающий за письмо:

```
class ContactForm extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
public $firstName;
public $lastName;
public $email;
public $subjectForm;
public $messageForm;

public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $email, $subjectForm, $messageForm)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
    $this->email = $email;
    $this->subjectForm = $subjectForm;
    $this->messageForm = $messageForm;
}


public function build()
{
     return $this->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'))
            ->subject("Письмо с формы контактов")
            ->view('emails.contact.request');
}  $this->url = Request::getHost()."/".$url;
        $this->text = $text;
    }
}
```

-- Вьюха:

```
<div>
  First Name: {{ $firstName }}
</div>  
<div>  
  Last Name: {{ $lastName }}
</div>  
<div>  
  Email: {{ $email }}
</div>  
<div>  
  Subject: {{ $subjectForm }}
</div>  
<div>  
  Message: {{ $messageForm }}
</div>
```

Подробнее:
https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/queues - очереди

https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/mail - отправка email